# Facebook OG Debugger showing share dialog correctly, but share dialog on website is not sending to Facebook correctly?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'll start by saying i'm a noob.

Question is, I have a website with multiple articles on one page and want to separate the facebook like/share buttons so when clicked they apply to the correct article.  After looking through the forums, I found I could create dummy pages with applicable og tags and have it redirected to the url which has all the article and like/share buttons.

Here is my dummy page (dummy_02.html):

```
    <head>
        <title>Michigan Game 1 Review</title>  

        <meta property="og:title" content="Devin & Devin lead Michigan over Appalachian State" />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Scarlet & Maize" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.scarletandmaize.com/dummy_02" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="Gardner to Funchess. Gardner to Funchess. Gardner to Funchess. This looks to be a common call this year, as the two connected for three first half touchdownsin a row on Saturday at the Big House. Derrick Green and De&#39Veon Smith took over from there totaling 285 yards and..." />
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://scarletandmaize.com/um_qb1.png" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.scarletandmaize.com/gameday">
    </head>
```

The above seems to be working correctly (I also have a dummy_01.html).

From there, I then went to the redirect page ("www.scarletandmaize.com/gameday") which contains the articles and fb buttons and posted the following code in the article header:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://scarletandmaize.com/dummy_02" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
```

From here, I went to the Facebook Open Graph Debugger to test things and no errors showed up and when clicking the 'See this in the share dialog.' link, it looks perfectly how I want it to appear on facebook.

My question now arises when I go to my website URL (www.scarletandmaize.com/gameday) and click the share button that was set to dummy_02 and all that appear in the share dialog is a white box with my websites index page (www.scarletandmaize.com) in the top left corner and bottom left corner. The images is not displayed, the description is not displayed and the title of the article is not displayed?!?!

Thanks for any and all help. The next beer (or coke) is on me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://scarletandmaize.com/dummy_02" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
```

Found a typo in the above HTML code. Should be "http://url.com", not "https://url.com"